# Custom Function to Change the Font Size of a Specified Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am trying to create a custom function with Google apps script which achieves the following goal:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uFOg.png)

To do this I have created the following Apps Script function:

```
function changeFontSize(cell,size) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange(cell)
  range.setFontSize(size);
}
```

And combined it with the following formula:

```
=IF(B2="Heading",changeFontSize(B3,18),changeFontSize(B3,12))
```

This returns the following error:

> Exception: Range not found (line 3).

Why is this occuring and how can I adapt my function to correctly achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that the reason of your issue of `Exception: Range not found` is due to `B3` of `=IF(B2="Heading",changeFontSize(B3,18),changeFontSize(B3,12))`. In this case, the value of cell "B3" is given. If the value of cell "B3" is the A1Notation, no error might occur. But, from your current error message, I thought that the value might not be the A1Notation.
- And also, even when `B3` of `=IF(B2="Heading",changeFontSize(B3,18),changeFontSize(B3,12))` is the A1Notation, I think that an error occurs. Because in the current stage, `setFontSize` cannot be used with the custom function. Unfortunately, it seems that this is the current specification.

From the above situation, in order to achieve your goal, how about using a simple trigger of OnEdit? The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const fontSize1 = 18; // Please set the font size.
  const fontSize2 = 12; // Please set the font size.

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.getA1Notation() != "B2") return;
  range.offset(1, 0).setFontSize(range.getValue() == "Heading" ? fontSize1 : fontSize2);
}
```

- When you use this script, please set the value of `Heading` to the cell "B2". By this, the font size of the cell "B3" is changed to `18`. And, when the cell "B2" is not `Heading`, the font size is changed to `12`.

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

### Added 1:

From your following 2nd question,

> I was also hoping to expand this functionality for an entire column. So any cells within a column that contain "Heading" the cell below will be size 18 font. Is there a way to expand your solution to work for all instances within an entire column?

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please set the header row.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const fontSize1 = 18; // Please set the font size.
  const fontSize2 = 12; // Please set the font size.
  const headerRow = 2; // Please set the header row. From your showing sample, 2 is used.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const lastRow = values.length;
  const { font1, font2 } = values[headerRow - 1].reduce((o, h, c) => {
    o[h == "Heading" ? "font1" : "font2"].push(sheet.getRange(headerRow + 1, c + 1, lastRow - headerRow, 1).getA1Notation());
    return o;
  }, { font1: [], font2: [] });
  if (font1.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRangeList(font1).setFontSize(fontSize1);
  }
  if (font2.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRangeList(font2).setFontSize(fontSize2);
  }
}
```

- In this case, when you run this script with the script editor, the values of header row is checked and the font size is changed.

### Added 2:

About your 2nd question, how about the following script?

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const fontSize1 = 18; // Please set the font size.
  const fontSize2 = 12; // Please set the font size.
  const column = 2; // Please set the column number.
  const headerTitle = "Heading";

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(1, column, sheet.getLastRow());
  const { s1, s2 } = range.createTextFinder(headerTitle).matchEntireCell(true).findAll().reduce((o, r) => {
    o.s1.push(r.offset(1, 0).getA1Notation());
    o.s2.push(r.getA1Notation());
    return o;
  }, { s1: [], s2: [] });
  if (s2.length == 0) return;
  [[s1, fontSize1], [s2, fontSize2]].forEach(([r, s]) => sheet.getRangeList(r).setFontSize(s));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was also hoping to expand this functionality for an entire column. So any cells within a column that contain "Heading" the cell below will be size 18 font. Is there a way to expand your solution to work for all instances within an entire column?

Comment: @jackratt Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your 2nd question, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your 2nd question, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This isn't quite what I was looking for. Your script results in the entire column having a font size of 18 when "Heading" is in B2. What I am looking for is to have multiple instances of "Heading" within column B and only have the cell directly below and instance of "Heading" be size 18 font, leaving the rest of the column size 12.

Comment: @jackratt Thank you for your response. I had understood that your posted question was resolved. Isn't my understanding correct? And, unfortunately, I cannot understand your 2nd question of `What I am looking for is to have multiple instances of "Heading" within column B and only have the cell directly below and instance of "Heading" be size 18 font, leaving the rest of the column size 12.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your 2nd question?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. My initial question was resolved however in hindsight I should have better explained my end goal. Maybe this example sheet will better demonstrate what I am trying to achieve. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DazoUPjfnG5z1fkl4rt3XZ2XyUo5HISLYSLq-XAh0-E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @jackratt Thank you for replying. About your 2nd question, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is almost exactly what I am looking for. When "Heading" is in a cell the cell below becomes size 18 font which is perfect. However if I then remove "Heading" or replace it with some other text, the cell below remains size 18. Is there a way to have the cell below revert to size 12 if "Heading" is removed?

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance with this! I have posted my new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73611628/changing-the-font-size-of-a-specified-cell)

Comment: @jackratt Thank you for your response. Now, when I saw your new question, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I believe your new question will be resolved by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

this would work for what you are asking, in your follow-up question to Tanaike, but you should probably add in some other conditions.
Also, The first response is correct about your script not being possible and their solution is a good one, but your specific error was actually because the B3 needed to be passed to the function as a string: "B3"

```
function onEdit(e){
  changeColumnFontSizeOnHeaderName(e);
}

function changeColumnFontSizeOnHeaderName(e) {
  const getColIndexBy = (table,header_name) => table[0].indexOf(header_name); 
  const getTableValuesBy = (sheet) => sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).isBlank() ? [] : Array.from(sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()); 

  const header_name = 'Heading';

  const fontSize1 = 18; // Please set the font size.
  const fontSize2 = 12; // Please set the font size.
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  const table = getTableValuesBy(sheet); //retrieves the shreadsheet as a table.
  const header_index = getColIndexBy(table,header_name); //Identifies the column index of your target header name.

  const last_row_with_data = sheet.getLastRow();
  const target_column = sheet.getRange(1,(header_index+1),last_row_with_data,1); //(starting row, starting column, last row, last column);
console.log(header_index+1)
  const is_heading_match = sheet.getRange(1,(header_index+1)).getValue() == header_name;

  const font_sizes_to_set = Array(last_row_with_data).fill().map(()=> is_heading_match ? [fontSize1] : [fontSize2]);

  target_column.setFontSizes(font_sizes_to_set);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Unfortuntaly when using this script I don't seem to get any sort of result. I have tried running manually instead of using onEdit and the execution log gives me the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined