# Changing the font size of a specified cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

### Problem

I have a spreadsheet with a number of headings in a column B which I am attempting to change the font size of.

If a cell in column B contains the text "Heading" I would like the cell directly below it to increase to size 18 font.

All other text in column B without "Heading" in the cell directly above should be size 12, including the cell containing the word "Heading".

For example - if cell B5 contains "Heading" then cell B6 should be size 18 font. The rest of column B should remain as size 12 font including cell B5. If cell B5 no longer contains "Heading" then cell B6 should revert to size 12 font.

### Current Progress

With the help of user Tanaike on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73500310/custom-function-to-change-the-font-size-of-a-specified-cell/73500587?noredirect=1#comment129985690_73500587) I now have the below script. This script will find any cell within column B that contains "Heading" and increase the font size of the cell directly below it to size 18 font. It will not however revert the cell back to size 12 font when "Heading" is removed from the cell directly above and is now empty or contains some other text.

### Question

How can this script be expanded upon to not only increase the font size of a cell to 18 when "Heading" is present in the cell directly above but also reduce the font size back to 12 when "Heading" is no longer present in the cell directly above?

```
function onEdit() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const fontSize1 = 18; // Please set the font size.
  const fontSize2 = 12; // Please set the font size.
  const column = 2; // Please set the column number.
  const headerTitle = "Heading";

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(1, column, sheet.getLastRow());
  const { s1, s2 } = range.createTextFinder(headerTitle).matchEntireCell(true).findAll().reduce((o, r) => {
    o.s1.push(r.offset(1, 0).getA1Notation());
    o.s2.push(r.getA1Notation());
    return o;
  }, { s1: [], s2: [] });
  if (s2.length == 0) return;
  [[s1, fontSize1], [s2, fontSize2]].forEach(([r, s]) => sheet.getRangeList(r).setFontSize(s));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement this functionality from the code bellow:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const fontSize1 = 18;
  const fontSize2 = 12;
  const headerTitle = "Heading";

  const value = e.value.toString();
  const oldValue = e.oldValue.toString();

  if (!oldValue.match(headerTitle) && value.match(headerTitle)) {
    e.source.toast(e.range.getA1Notation() + ' --> font size: ' + fontSize1);
    e.range.offset(1, 0).setFontSize(fontSize1);
    return;
  }

  if (oldValue.match(headerTitle) && !value.match(headerTitle)) {
    e.source.toast(e.range.getA1Notation() + ' --> font size: ' + fontSize2);
    e.range.offset(1, 0).setFontSize(fontSize2)
    return;
  }
}
```

But it has a big flaw. It works only when you're editing the cells manually. It wont work when you're pasting a text into a cell via <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or changing several cells at once. It doesn't even work when you're removing a cell content with <kbd>Delete</kbd> button. Etc

**Update**

Here is the simple static function that sets font size 18 for the cells that have the title 'Heading' in the cell above and sets font size 12 for the rest cells in column B:

```
function change_font_sizes() {
  const size1  = 18;
  const size2  = 12;
  const title  = 'Heading';
  const sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range  = sheet.getRange('B1:B' + sheet.getLastRow());
  const sizes  = range.getFontSizes();
  const values = range.getDisplayValues().flat().slice(0,-1); // remove the last cell

  values.forEach((value,i) => sizes[i+1][0] = value.match(title) ? size1 : size2);
  range.setFontSizes(sizes);
}
```

You can run this function manually every time you feel your sheet needs it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't seem to get this script working. Does it need a SpreadsheetApp variable that points to the desired sheet? The flaws you have described may hold me back as I am looking for the script to update based on data  which may change that is being pulled from another sheet using IMPORTRANGE. Would a good way round this be to change this to a customFunction that can be run on a trigger when the sheet is opened rather than using onEdit?

Comment: It doesn't need SpreadsheetApp variable. It gets a current sheet and a cell from the event object `spreadsheet = e.source`, `current_cell = e.range`. But if you're using importrange this script wont work. This function (trigger) `onEdit()` fires only if you change cell contents manually (and even in this case it has many limitations). There is another trigger `onChange()` (installable) it's able to catch ctrl+v, ctrl+x and deletions. But changes with importrange are most likely off limits of any trigger, as far as I know. I have no good answer.

Comment: Probably you have to give up `onEdit()` functionality and use a simply static script that you can run manually whenever you need. It will check all the cells and make the desired changes on the sheet.

Comment: Thankyou, I suspected that may be the case. Are you able to assist in adapting the script to be static?

Comment: I think I can do it. Could you show a screenshot of your sheet. Just to be sure that I correct understand the task.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have decided to approach my problem in a different way and abandon this script as I think I have overcomplicated what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Well. Nevertheless I've added in my answer an example of the simply static function to change font sizes.